# Solving non-linear ODE with MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to solve an ODE on the form

y'' = (x-y)^3/2

with the boundary conditions y(0)=0, y'(a)=0

Is there a simple numerical solver for this type of equation. I tried to look in their solvers for boundary problems but did not find much help. If anyone has a few lines of codes for solving this problem it would be very helpful!

Comment: Yes, there is https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html

Comment: [`bvp4c`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bvp4c.html) is the standard BVP solver.